# Keep state of richfaces:tabPanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a richfaces:tabPanel. Users select one tab, then click on a link and go to the next site. When they click the back button in the browser, I want the last opened tab to be open again. This is what I have so far:

```
<rich:tabPanel [...] selectedTab="#{search.openTabPanel}">

        <a4j:support event="ontabchange"
            action="#{search.tabChanged}" ajaxSingle="true" />

        <rich:tab 
            name="tabPanelProduction" [...] />

</rich:tabPanel>
```

In my class in Search.java, the name of the currently opened tab is stored in a String object calles openTabPanel, the set method is always called when the tab is changed. The method tabChanged() doesn't do anything, but without it the setter would not be called if the tab is changed..

Comment: Richfaces provides the `activeItem` attribute for the tabpanel. You could easily restore the state of tab using that